# data driven in the conditional logic does't work as expected

Tags: karate

I'd like to data-driven test another feature files in the conditional logic (normal programming language there is if - else if - else if - else, but maybe not support in karate for more than two conditions).

**Here is my demo feature file:**

```
Feature: conditional logic call demo

  Scenario:

    * def switchVar1 = 1
    * def switchVar2 = 2

    * table testVars
    |switchVar1|switchVar2|
    |'theOne1'  | 'theTwo1' |
    |'theOne2'  | 'theTwo2' |


# here I can not do data-driven test the feature file: 'callUsage/module1/demo_module1.feature' 
 * eval if(switchVar1 == 1) 
     karate.call('classpath:callUsage/module1/demo_module1.feature') testVars
```

**the error log**

```
flow.feature:30 - javascript evaluation failed: if(switchVar1 == 1) karate.call('classpath:callUsage/module1/demo_module1.feature') testVars, <eval>:1:84 Expected ; but found testVars
if(switchVar1 == 1) karate.call('classpath:callUsage/module1/demo_module1.feature') testVars
                                                                                    ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 84
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing value to `karate.call` is different from `call` as `karate.call` should be invoked like a function

try,

```
* eval if(switchVar1 == 1) karate.call('<FILE_PATH>', testVars)
```

https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-call

Comment: Wow,  I see. Sorry for my misunderstanding  about the "call" usage.